# Button remains toggled with preventDefault

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom-events

I have a `<button>` inside a form. In its event handler, I call to `preventDefault` so clicking the button doesn't cause the form to be submitted.

Problem is, this causes the button to remain toggled, as if you clicked the button holding the cursor.

**How to restore button toggling while still preventing form submission?**

---

**Update:** issue persists even if I place the button outside the form, i.e. it has nothing to do with `preventDefault` as I incorrectly diagnosed.

Apologies for a misguided question.

Comment: Did you try using `return false` at the end of the handler instead of `preventDefault`?

Comment: While you use `click` event on the button to handle, it won't be a problem.

Comment: @matewka yes I have tried both jQuery's `preventDefault`, and `return false`.

Comment: @ManoloSalsas What do you mean? I handle the click event using `$('#foo').click(function(e){...})`, and call to `e.preventDefault` within the function.

Comment: Could you supply a JSFiddle to re-create the issue? I can't seem to get it with the following code : http://jsfiddle.net/Nunners/Sw6N4/

Comment: Does the button you are using ever need to submit the form? i.e. is the `e.preventDefault()` only called on a condition or on every click regardless?

Comment: I mean, what's your coding issue?

Comment: @ManoloSalsas The button keeps looking toggled after the click

Comment: @Nunners there are no conditionals. But I can't place the button outside the form - that would yield malformed html

Comment: can you provide code that would be more helpful to understand your exact problem.

Comment: I'm afraid I failed to reproduce the issue from scratch. Must have to do with Rails/Bootstrap.

Answer (score 1):

If you wish to prevent Form Submission with a `<button>` element you can set the `type` to be `button`, i.e. : `<button type="button">`.

By default the type of a `button` object is Submit which is causing the form to submit. You can prevent this by changing the type.

By changing the type you are changing the button, this new button will never submit the form unless you **manually submit** it by use of some Javascript.

Comment: Thank you for a useful piece of information - I find preventing form submission via html cleaner than via JS. It didn't solve my issue though

Answer (score 0):

You could try this.

```
function checkForm(){

var form=document.forms[0];

if(form.name.value==''){  
 alert("enter name, please");
 return false;
    }

return true;

}



<form><input type="text" name="name"><input type="submit" onclick="return checkForm()"></form>
```

Comment: How is your answer even remotely related to my question?